# UIBarButton doesn't appear after editing

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I created an UIBarButton IBOutlet (add) on the right side and connected it to the UI. I also have a collection view and use the setEditing function to delete items from it.

If I press the edit Button on the left, delete Button appears on the right with which I can choose items to delete, but if I press edit again, delete button disappears and shows my add Button back.

```
IBOutlet weak var addItemButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

   self.collectionView!.allowsMultipleSelection = true
   ...

   if editing {
     // create navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
     // works fine
   } else {
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButton = addItemButton
   }
}
```

Everything works fine, but my addBarButton in the else statement **doesn't** appear, BUT if I create a button programmatically it works how expected.

```
...
} else {
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "addNewItem: ")
}
```

Why does my IBOutlet button not appear?

Comment: Did you connect `addItemButton` somewhere? If not the button is nil, and also what you are doing here is not suggested. Rather add it on interface builder and connect it, or just create it programmatically as you did.

Comment: of sure, its connected and done the functionality properly until I press the edit button and the delete button is appears instead the addButton, but if I switch back by tapping the edit button again, deleteButton disappears but don't the addButton